# Formula in Excel cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Trying to add vlookup formula in cell using VBA excel, but there is runtime error 1004.

My Code:-

```
Range(Cells(2, AgtColV.Column), Cells(LastRowMerge, AgtColV.Column)).Formula = _

    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'\\stor.site.com\s2\me\My Documents\[om_vlookup.xlsb]Agent_M'!$D:$E,2,0)),""NF"",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'\\stor.site.com\s2\me\My Documents\[om_vlookup.xlsb]Agent_M'!$D:$E,2,0)
```

I think the issue is because I am using $ in $D:$E

Comment: You're mixing R1C1 and A1 style references in the same formula, and  you can't do that. Use `C4:C5` instead of `$D:$E`

Comment: ^^^ and `.FormulaR1C1`